# migrate TFS 2013 SharePoint contents to SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2016

We are migrating from TFS 2013 to TFS 2018.  We heavily used the SharePoint
integration in TFS 2013 to categorize and maintain version history of
related project documentation within permission-restricted areas.  We would
like to migrate the documents and metadata from the SharePoint contents over
to SharePoint 2016 in some way that can still be relatable to TFS 2018.
Since TFS 2013 SharePoint contents are stored in the TFS database, is there
a way to migrate this data to a SharePoint 2016 database?
If not, is there another migration path available that would enable us to
continue having the version history, categorization, and permissions
features we need in TFS 2018?

Answer (score 1):

TFS 2018 [does not support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sharepoint-dashboards/about-sharepoint-integration?view=azure-devops) Sharepoint integration.

Your statement *"Since TFS 2013 SharePoint contents are stored in the TFS database"* is not correct -- Sharepoint content is stored in Sharepoint. You can migrate that Sharepoint instance however you'd like. However, in TFS 2018, there will be no integration, so the TFS-specific web parts in your Sharepoint site(s) will not be functional.

You simply need to [disable Sharepoint integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sharepoint-dashboards/deprecation/disable-tfs-sharepoint-integration-after-tfs-2018-upgrade?view=tfs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) after the upgrade to TFS 2018. There is also an [upgrade guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sharepoint-dashboards/deprecation/upgrade-from-sharepoint2013-to-sharepoint-2106?view=tfs-2017) to get you to Sharepoint 2016.